# Test if a string is text/sentence or symbols

Tags: python, image-processing, tesseract

I'm writing a ocr tool that takes crops. Most of the time the crops are of text, but sometimes the crop takes in a graph or image, and tesseract ocr outputs symbols.

Example legitimate text (small amount of non standard symbols/errors):

`Mode] for migration of zebras`

Example of graph ocr text:

`a S'I'Iill�`

How can I tell the difference between the two types of output?

Comment: It looks like `legitimate text` is ASCII and non`legitimate text` is any other encoding.  Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Nathaniel, that would work, but sometimes legit text has non ascii characters from ocr issues.

Comment: so it's more about the text being illegible than it having the � characters?

Comment: `nltk.corpus.words.words()` has a list of 236,000+ English words. If _a lot of_ (whatever it means) your OCR'ed words are not on the list, you must be dealing with trash.

Comment: Correct @nathanell